# Create a full screen overlay window in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'd like to create a full screen overlay window just like the one that pops up when you click one of the portfolio items in this demo (http://demo.themevan.com/simplekey/). I'm totally clueless as to how to achieve it, though.

I could just have a fixed div with 100% height\width kept hidden or at zero opacity and then displayed when the user clicks on the button, something like this:

```
<script>
$('.open_single_project').click(function(e){
    $('.single_project_modal_window').show().animate({
        opacity: 1
        }, 300, function() {
    });
});
```

But is it the best way to do this? Do you know of any plugin that could help me in this? 
Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've handled this similarly:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="divBlockEntirePage" style="display:none;"></div>
    ....
```

CSS:

```
#divBlockEntirePage
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divBlockEntirePage').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually called a "modal window" (or sometimes "lightbox" after one of the popular early Javascript modal window implementations).  Generally these only occupy a portion of the screen rather than all of it, but making it fullscreen would be a simple tweak in almost any common modal window plugin or script.

There are dozens of them out there depending on what exactly you want to do, but almost any of them would be appropriate for a full screen overlay (you will just need to tweak the JS options and CSS).  I usually use the versatile [Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) jQuery plugin for this, but there are also more lightweight plugins available, as well as implementations that are not dependent on jQuery.